# Respect Validation Rule email() Validates an email address ne fonctionne pas

Tags: php, assert, respect-validation

j'utilise la librairie respect\validation

pour checker l'email()
https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/Email/

```
v::email()->validate('alexandre@gaigalas.net'); // true
```

mais seulement si on ne précise pas le .net ça fonctionne quand même !!

```
v::email()->validate('alexandre@gaigalas'); // true
```

je cherche une solution,
merci

Comment: That is because `alexandre@gaigalas` is a valid email address, it is an address of the TLD (top level domain) `gaigalas`. The fact that this TLD doesn't exist is not checked. Please write your questions in English.

Comment: thanks, how to check if the domain really exists with this library

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is in English (http://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy)

Answer (score 2):

it's ok

i use

```
v::filterVar(FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)->validate('alexandre@gaigalas');// false
```